# Regression Analysis:

Tags: regression

[image: regression]linear regression model is fitting the data properly as in shape of the curve of predicted value is same as curve of actual value but the predicted values are lower than the actual values. Imagine the actual curve being pulled down in the graph to give predicted curve. Can anyone suggest why is this happening?
 In the image- black points are the actual value and red line is the fitted value, pink and blue are prediction interval value(prediction upper and prediction lower)
x axis is not an explanatory variable used to train the model, it is just the timestamp of data collection

Comment: There is almost certainly some problem in the way the regression model is set up. It would help to see how the model is set up and a plot of the data points and fitted curve.

Comment: reg<-lm(formula = Output ~ Power + Thermal+ Temperature + Hour , data = train)
summary(reg)
pred.interval<- predict(reg, test, interval ="prediction", level= 0.95)
i am not able to add photo of the curve, but imagine as the actual data point curve is bell shaped and it is pulled down from the middle to give fitted value curve(the fitted values are matching the data points at the end point of the data point curve but is pulled down in the centre). The fit and shape of the two curves are same. @EdM

Comment: What "curves" are you talking about? Your regression is multivariate; plotting the fit correctly would require five dimensions!  If you would care to post an image somewhere on the Web, you could link to it to show what's going on.

Comment: @whuber i am talking about the plot of output variable. My regression is multivariate and i am predicting output by using the linear regression model trained on train dataset. When i am plotting the actual output variable and predicted output variable(x axis is time)then the above described pattern is observed. (the data is not time series)

Comment: Is this pattern appearing when you score the same dataset that you trained your model on, or on a held out dataset?

Comment: @MatthewDrury The dataset is different- on held out dataset, the curve is fine for training dataset

Comment: This is a plot of the response (and, apparently, some predictions) against *one single explanatory variable.*  It tells you little (apart from that the model does not fit well).  There are (far) better ways [to evaluate your regression model.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+diagnostic+plot)

Comment: That was my suspicion.

Comment: the x axis is not one of the explanatory variables used to train the model, the goal was to check the value of predicted output over time and its fit with respect to actual value. @whuber

Comment: rmse value is close to 11 and 13 for training and validation data set

Comment: Could you explain the various colors and symbols in your plot?  Edit the question statement.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, The explanation is really helpful, can you suggest some remedial measure. and alos why arre the actual and fiited values matching in the ends of the curve

Comment: @MatthewDrury X axis is time of the data collection, black circles are actual values. Red line is the fitted value line, pink and blue lines are prediction interval line(prediction upper and prediction lower)
x axis is not any explanatory variable but the time of data collection

Comment: @MatthewDrury  the training data is of january month and the scoring is done on the february data of the same year. so i am not sure whether the lag impact could be a reason of such behavior of the model

Answer (score 1):

A linear model with an intercept term will always predict the mean of the response correctly  **on the training data**.  That is, the mean of the observed response is always equal to the mean of the predicted response.  You could say that the intercept "memorized" the overall response mean of the training data.

That said, when you go to a held out data set, there is no guarantee that the overall mean will stay the same.  This is especially true when your new data is collected out of time, or in a different region (or for many other reasons).  This phenomena is often manifested in exactly the way that you are seeing: the model captures the *shape* of the data well, but the overall trend is shifted by a constant amount.

I see this all the time in my industry (insurance).  There is a long lag from when a model is fit to when it can be put into production due to regulatory issues.  During this time, macroeconomic forces can cause the average insurance loss to drift up or down, while the *ratio* between the propensities for two customers to have a loss stays constant.  There is a whole gamut of techniques actuaries have developed to deal with these intercept shifts.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Can you suggest some remedial measure

Comment: Also, why is the model fitting for the values in the end.

Comment: What remedial measures you take, if any, is very dependent on what you actually want to use this model for / what you want to learn from the analysis.  It looks like your model is predicting too high at the boundaries of time, and too large in the middle, this is probably due to a model mis-specification (like a non-linear effect that is correlated with the time variable you are plotting).